# Inserting rows with input names

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, row

I'm having some issues with a system I am building.

**SHORT STORY**
I want to insert a row after I press a button but the row has 2 `<td>`s and they have to get the names for the modal's day so if I press on the button for Monday, the `<td>`'s name has to be `name="Ma0_HrFrom"`. And the next row after that has to have the name `Ma1_HrFrom`.

**LONG STORY**
I am working on adding an Expert availability section to it, where experts can fill in a week number and then they see a week with the week days and dates. After the days there is a button which pops up a bootstrap modal. There is a table with one row already. But on one day experts can work from 0800 till 1000 and between 1000 until 1400. They can also have breaks. So I want to insert a new row when I press on an `<a></a>`.

The row adding works almost, the problem is I can't get to figure out how to fill in the selects and the name of the select.

My code for now is below:

```js
    var dagen = ["Ma", "Di", "Wo", "Do", "Vr", "Za", "Zo"];
    var lengte = dagen.length;
    var i = 0;
    var s;
    $('[name="addRow"]').click(function () 
    {

        s = 0;
        do
        {


             var test = $('select [name="'+ dagen[i] +'_uurVan"]').clone().attr('name', dagen[i] + i + '_uurVan').val();
             console.log(test);
            console.log("Dagen i = " + dagen[i]);
            if (s < 1)
            {
                $('<tr><td name="test">' + test + '</td><td>' + 'selectTot' + '</td></tr>').insertBefore($(this).closest('tr'));
                //test.append('[name="test"]');

            }
            s++;
            i++;
        }while(i < lengte);



    });
```

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle out of this? With you html as well

Comment: i tried but no too much diffrent stylesheets etc. but i already figured a bit out so thanks tho

Comment: If you construct HTML using JavaScript string concatenation, you're gonna have a bad time.

Comment: @cvrebert exactly... how could i been so wrong xD